# Replace original record with another on during After / Before Insert

Tags: apex, trigger, json, dml, deserialize

Imagine the user clicks a standard New button of a custom objects, populates some fields (in a Standard Layout) and then clicks save.

He then is redirected to the View page of this new record, but is many fields and related lists a populates with values and child records from a hidden template inside the app.

This all would be easy if the structure I am going to deserialize would be stand alone and not dependand on a parent record NOT part of the template.

I therefore required the user to manually populate a parent lookup field and the want to do this in the Before or Aftert Insert trigger:

1. Get the lookup value from the user's record (temporary)
2. Deserialize the serialized record (real) using the lookup value
3. Delete the users record

**Now my question: How can a trigger cancel inserting the original record and instead insert and redirect to another?**

Comment: Is the deserialized record of the same sObject type as the one being saved initially?

Comment: It is a tree strucure where the Root is a Record of Same Type

Comment: Can't be done in a trigger. I think you're going to have to use VF somewhere.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Any reference where this is documented?

Comment: @AdrianLarson just add that as answer and I can credit you some points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records cannot be removed from a trigger context collection, as it is immutable.

You are going to need to implement a `VisualForce` workaround to get the functonality you desire. You will then want to use this `Page` to override the `New` action on your object.